# setting an initial cluster strcuture for hierarchical clustering algorithms

Tags: python, initialization, hierarchical-clustering

Typically, in Hierarchical clustering, the algorithm starts with each point being in its own group, and then combining groups based on ma given metric.

Is there a way to initialize the algorithm with a given starting groups other than single points?

python or R is fine

Answer (score 0):

The hierarchical algorithm itself doesn't prevent you from starting with an initial cluster structure, provided you have the cluster data required to evaluate your metric in each of the cases:

- Distance between two points: e.g. euclidean distance
- Distance between a point and a cluster: e.g. euclidean distance between the point and the cluster's centroid.
- Distance between two clusters: e.g. euclidean distance between both centroids.

The problem may be finding a library that allows doing so.

You could use [Scipy hiearchical clustering](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/cluster.hierarchy.html) inputting your initial clusters as points (represented by their centroids), but this would work only for the 'centroid' method, not for the 'single' or 'complete' methods.

The algorithm itself is simple:

- While there is more than one cluster or individual point

  - Calculate the triangular matrix of distances between them
  - Find clusters or points at minimum distance and combine them in a new cluster

So coding it with an arbitrary initial structure is straightforward.