# Is it possible to pre-specify a cluster structure and then merge it according to common clustering criteria in R?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means, hierarchical-clustering

Suppose that I had a dataset where I've done a cluster analysis with, say, k=9. Perhaps this has been from a k-means or I've just done a complete linkage hierarchical agglomeration or I eyeballed it from a scatter plot, I don't think how I got the k=9 matters.* Suppose now that I want k=5 clusters instead but I want to proceed from my k=9 cluster result to obtain these k=5 clusters. And finally suppose that I wanted the merge to proceed according to the principles of, say, k-means (as in, which merge to k=8 from k=9 minimises WSS), complete linkage etc. Is there any way I can do this in R? Or would I have to write my own function?

Essentially, what if I wanted to create a hierarchical agglomerative structure where I don't start with k=N singleton clusters? Can I do that in R without having to write my own function?

Mainly**, what I've tried to do is search for a solution. Someone asked a similar question for Python (amd would've accepted R answers) but [only got an answer relevant only sort of relevant to centroid linkage.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65615873/setting-an-initial-cluster-strcuture-for-hierarchical-clustering-algorithms) Centroid linkage has problems with what, iirc, are called reversals and also I don't think that would even work after merging the singletons (unless I'm making a terrible error, the new centroid of a merge isn't going to be the centroid of the two centroids unless the merged clusters have the same number of members).

---

*In practice, I have a fairly unstable k=5 k means segmentation and I generated a matrix representing the instability across 1009 segmentations. I then tried to create what I guess we might call the modal cluster, but my code is flawed and thus I'm trying to fudge it by going from the k=9  structure my flawed code produces to the desired k=5 segmentation.

**In terms of my specific problem, I've also treated the matrix of 100-% of times colocated values as a distance object and used it to do a hierarchical cluster. I think that'll do as an alternative to my flawed code, but it don't *think* it addresses the central question of how to pre-specify a cluster structure and then merge down from it. This "solution" was [inspired by this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529625/is-it-possible-to-specify-your-own-distance-function-using-scikit-learn-k-means) Also, this is what it generates as a complete linkage fit for my data:

[image: as you can see, it's not binary splits, though I can get k=5, I'm not confident it'd always work for every k]

Answer (score 0):

So, I think I understand what you are saying you want. My concern is your desire to define a set of 5 centroids (or set of 5) and then ask R to make 9 clusters into those specific 5.

That defeats the purpose of a cluster analysis. With a cluster model you are sussing out inherent structure in your data. The model defines the clusters not based on practicality, but internal data structure.

If you only want 5 clusters, then you have to specify that somehow, and accept that you may not have the optimal number to build the most robust set of clusters possible.

If I were to guess, the end goal is to make unsupervised model behave like a supervised model..but it is not supposed to work that way.

You have some decisions to make:

- cluster robustly with the optimal number (k=9)
- cluster less robustly using k=5
- Do extensive exploration of the 9 clusters & 5 clusters to see if meaningful real-world segments appear, and then use what you have learned exploring to create classes and labels for all your data and rely on a supervised model as your end model to associate new datapoints with your existing cluster-based classes

I am sure that is not what you were looking for, but any attempt to coerce the centroid, nullifies the whole point of pattern detection...in my less than authoritative opinion.